# How to show available Typography settings by default in Gutenberg Block Editor?

Tags: block-editor

From [this article](https://wpdevelopment.courses/articles/block-editor-typography-settings/#h-what-are-the-typography-settings):

[image]

How can I control which settings are shown by default?

Comment: Are you trying to do this in a theme you’ve authored, or just on a site your running with a downloaded theme?

Comment: I am trying to do it in TwentyTwentyOne theme.